# Categorize records with specific values java

Tags: java, hibernate, loops, collections

I have a related records like below, this records i will be getting from hibernate layers

```
camps batchs values
camp1  b1       300
camp2  b1       67
camp3  b2       8
camp4  b2       90
camp5  b3       78
camp6  b3       23
camp7  b1       89
```

i would like to categorize in order like below using collections, with key indicating for which batch records belong to

Required output :

```
 b1 :
    camp1 300
    camp2 67
    camp3 0
    camp4 0
    camp5 0
    camp6 0
    camp7 89

b2:
camp1 0
camp2 0
camp3 8
camp4 90
camp5 0
camp6 0
camp7 0

b3:
camp1 0
camp2 0
camp3 0
camp4 0
camp5 78
camp6 23
camp7 0
```

Now, i have below code. I am stuck here to get required output.

```
for(Camapign cmp : campList){
batch  b = getBatchByCamp(cmp.getId());
int val = getValuesByCamp(cmp.getId());
// need to put logic to get required o/p
}
```

Can any body help me in this.

Comment: Does Campaign have a getBatchs() method?

Comment: @Bohemian Each campaign have campaign Id, by campaign Id calling service, i can get batch attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a `Map<Batch, Map<Campaign, Integer>>` from a list of `Campaign` given some functions to calculate various attributes:

```
List<Campaign> campaigns; // given a list of Campaign

Map<Batch, Map<Campaign, Integer>> grouped = campaigns.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    cmp -> getBatchByCamp(cmp.getId()),
    cmp -> new Map<Campaign, Integer>(){{put(cmp, getValuesByCamp(cmp.getId()));}},
    (a, b) -> {a.putAll(b); return a;})
   );
```

Comment: Thanks, i am using java7, can you please put java7 code.

Comment: @Daisy. Java 8 has been out more than 3 years and we are up to java 9 now. I won't post code for an deprecated java version. Please upgrade.

Comment: i agree, but our application is based on java7, sp can you please atleast put pseduo code. so i can understand? Please

Comment: @daisy start by creating a map of type `Map<Batch, Map<Campaign, Integer>>`, then in the loop put stuff in it

Comment: can you please put code related to it. Stuffing the map with logic to give required result is what i dont know. It will be vary helpful